# Combinations with repetition: Why is this question solved using arrangements/permutations with repetitons?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> In how many ways can we select five coins from a collection of $10$ consisting of one penny, one nickel, one dime, one quarter, one half-dollar, and five (identical) Susan B. Anthony dollars?

The answer is $2^5$, which does not make sense to me.  Since this is a combinations with repetitions question, why does it use the arrangements formula: $n^r$. Shouldn't the answer be $\binom{14}{5}$, from using the combinations with repetitions formula?

Comment: As the dollars are identical, this is really a question about which non-dollar coins are chosen. Any subset of the five smaller coins can be chosen.

Comment: true but since this question is taken from a chapter dealing with combinations with repetitions why is a different concept(permutations with repetition/arrangements) used instead of combinations with repetition C(n+r-1, r)

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The five coins can be $k$ coins taken from  the set of one penny, one nickel, one dime, one quarter, one half-dollar ($5$ distinct elements) and $5-k$ identical Susan B. Anthony dollars for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$. Therefore the number of ways to select them is
$$\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{5}{k}=(1+1)^5=2^5.$$

Comment: @PatrickPichart The person who asked can vote one or more answers and mark one answer as "accepted". Please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/tour